# GNU Assembler: Set fixed displacement size

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, gnu-assembler, machine-code

I am looking for a way to enforce a 32 bit width for any machine code displacements. Usually the size of the displacement is dependent on the actual value, e.g. a displacement of 5 will result in a single byte value.

Is there a command line option or something similar to achieve this?

I checked some documentation and only found some pre-/suffixes like {disp32} that you can use in asm itself. I need it to work from the command line during the gcc build process.

Comment: I don't think there's a gcc option for that.  What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: I am writing my bachelor's thesis about performing the RandStruct feature (randomizing the order of struct members) on the linux kernel after it was already compiled. To do so, I automatically scan the binary for instructions that access a struct member I want to move and replace the offset. Moving a member from the first 256 bytes to something further in the back of the struct, results in a longer instruction currently and thus I can not just leave everything else as it is. I would need to reassemble the entire binary.

Comment: Perhaps scan the asm source instead so you can make changes at that point, only for pointer derefs that actually need it?  If you can move the first member of a struct, a "disp0" (no displacement) could have to change into a disp8 (-128..+127) or disp32, so you'd potentially need to bload *every* dereference.  Making *every* addressing mode need a 4-byte disp32 could suck for performance (I-cache and uop-cache hit rate).  Even `16(%rsp)` could need it in case a large struct was stored on the stack, although kernel code probably usually avoids that?

Comment: Or if you really want to modify binaries, you could still add a processing step that modifies the asm source as part of building `.o` files.  Like `gcc -S foo.c` / modify  `foo.s` / `gcc -c foo.s`.  (Maybe with a tmp file or a separate build directory in case the source has `foo.c` and `foo.s`, although probably most asm source files will be `.S`)

Comment: I don't think what you are attempting is generally feasible but it might work with optimisations reduced.  One thing you could do is e.g. never shuffle structure members that are before the 256B mark to after that mark.  This way the displacements do not need to be made longer.  Or patch binutils to always produce full displacements.  But be careful: 0 byte displacement is also a choice and usually used for the first structure member.

Comment: I ran into the issue with the first struct member way earlier and took the dirty way to avoid the issue by just adding a dummy byte in the beginning of the struct that can never be randomized. Also the task_struct (my main interest) is not supposed to be randomized in the beginning anyways so that is no problem for me currently. Just not randomizing the first 256 bytes is my current favourite to keep going without investing too much time into this problem. However, I might try to change the binutils wherever it is checking for the disp32 prefix and just make it act like it was there.

Comment: My supervisor also suggested that I could try to remove the according opcodes from GAS entirely, so it just can't produce instructions with smaller displacements. However, that sounds tedious to me, as there is not just one type of instruction that can access a struct's member.

Comment: @PeterCordes unfortunately I can neither modify the asm, nor add a build step as I am trying to make the entire thing get to a working binary as quickly as possible. Performing at least the entire linking stage afterwards would simply take too long in my case.

Comment: My second comment (of processing the asm between compile and assemble to add `{disp32}` to every addressing mode or even every line) would produce a linked binary with disp32 for every addressing mode, like you asked for.

Comment: @fuz: It's not the 256-byte mark that matters.  With signed disp8 displacements, it's the 128-byte mark.  Good idea to separately randomize the first part and second part, so disp8-reachable stuff stays reachable with a disp8, but you can still randomize everything unless the struct size was 132 bytes or something so there's just one member that needed a disp32.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes yes of course.

Comment: @JasperNiebuhr I don't think it would be very hard to hack the assembler such that it treats every memory operand as if `{disp32}`  has been supplied.  Just check for the code that handles `{disp32}` and set the corresponding bit always.